# SpiceLogic PayPal Control Upgrade to v 4

Tags: paypal

We are in a process of upgrading SpiceLogic PayPal control to the latest version 4 to address PayPal's new security requirements. As per SpiceLogic site - no APIs in their control were changed. So it should be a breeze.

However new control doesn't compile with project giving an error message: `Type or namespace SpiceLogic could not be found ...`

The reference to SpiceLogic .dll was manually added to VS solution and we can see it in VS 2010 Solution Explorer's `references` folder. Adding this .dll reference via `Project ==> Add Reference ...` also doesn't help.

We are using VS 2010 Ultimate edition which runs in .NET v 4.0. SpiceLogic control requires 4.5. Could that be a reason?

Comment: That's _likely_ because **TLS 1.2** support starts in v4.5 of the framework - which coincides with [Paypal's security update notice](https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/#tls). Assuming 4.5 is installed (OS), **try**  _manually_ adding the assembly to `/bin` and see if that works (instead of referencing)...

Answer (score 0):

The older version of the SpiceLogic PayPal Control did not use .NET Framework 4.5. After the PayPal security requirement changed, SpiceLogic released a new version targeting .NET Framework 4.5. So, if you use the latest version of the control, you should not have any problem.